# C# Windows Media Player Ctlcontrols.play() doesn't work

Tags: c#, wmp

I created a program that reads an MP4 file from disk (it doens't have extension) and autoplays it:

```
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer MediaPlayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer.settings.autoStart = true;
MediaPlayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);
MediaPlayer.uiMode = "mini";
MediaPlayer.URL = file to open;
MediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

It doens't matter what option I change, if autoStart is set to true or false, it will NEVER autoplay and I always have to click the button. However Ctlcontrols.play() seems to work if, for example, I press a key to first Invoke Ctlcontrols.stop() and then another key for Ctlcontrols.play()

Comment: You might be able to tell it to play after the media has opened. Check out the MediaPlayer.MediaOpened Event. I don't know how to embed links into comments so here's the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaopened(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have added the mediaplayer component from wmp.dll (when you choose the elements under COM tab) so there is no MediaOpened event